# .net Maui Getting an: [System] A resource failed to call close

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, maui

When I run the following code I get an:

[System] A resource failed to call close.

```
 [RelayCommand]
  public async void ImportData ()
  {
    IsBusy = true;
    Console.WriteLine("Import data");
    //create custom filetypes
    var customFileType = new FilePickerFileType(
      new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>>
      {
          { DevicePlatform.Android, new[] { "application/json" } },
      });

    PickOptions options = new()
    {
      PickerTitle = "", //Only works for ios
      FileTypes = customFileType,
    };

    //get filepicker for friends.json
    Console.WriteLine($"Import friends");
    options.PickerTitle = "Please select friends.json file";

    await GrabFriends(options);
    Console.WriteLine("Friends imported.");


    Console.WriteLine($"Import groups");
    options.PickerTitle = "Please select groups.json file";

    await GrabGroups(options);
    Console.WriteLine("Groups imported");

    //refresh
    List<Friend> l = await App.Database.GetFriendsAsync();
    FriendsOC = new ObservableCollection<Friend>(l);

    IsBusy = false; 
  }

  public static async Task<FileResult> GrabFriends(PickOptions options)
  {
    await App.Database.DeleteAllFriendsAsync();
    try
    {
      var result = await FilePicker.Default.PickAsync(options);
      if (result != null)
      {
        using var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();
        var friendsjson = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Friend>>(stream);

        //Go through list and add to db
        foreach (Friend f in friendsjson)
        {
          await App.Database.SaveFriendAsync(f);
        }

        stream.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("GM: JSON file data loaded");

      }

      return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("GM: Ooops in Json : " + ex.Message);
    }

    return null;
  }
```

Here is the output

```
[DOTNET] Import data
[DOTNET] Import friends
[DOTNET] GM: JSON file data loaded
[DOTNET] Friends imported.
[DOTNET] Import groups
[DOTNET] GM: Group JSON file data loaded
[DOTNET] Groups imported
[donmoore.censu] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 20289(832KB) AllocSpace objects, 8(192KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 4337KB/8674KB, paused 540us total 20.661ms
[donmoore.censu] Reducing the number of considered missed Gc histogram windows from 325 to 100
[System] A resource failed to call close. 
[chatty] uid=10167(uk.co.gordonmoore.census) FinalizerDaemon identical 2 lines
[System] A resource failed to call close. 
[donmoore.censu] Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 3561(163KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 4382KB/8764KB, paused 546us total 16.534ms
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #116
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #117
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #117
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #114
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #112
The thread 0x75 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x72 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x70 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #118
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #115
The thread 0x73 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #119
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #118
The thread 0x76 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

It all works fine. I thought it might be in the stream object, but that didn't work.

There are calls to a sqlite database object as well

```
namespace Census.Database;

public class Database
{
  private readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection _database;

  public Database(string dbPath)
  {
    _database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
    _database.CreateTableAsync<Friend>();
    _database.CreateTableAsync<FSGroup>();
  }

  public Task<List<Friend>> GetFriendsAsync()
  {
    return _database.Table<Friend>().ToListAsync();
  }

  public Task<Friend> GetFriendAsync(int id)
  {
    return _database.GetAsync<Friend>(id);
  }

  public Task<int> SaveFriendAsync(Friend friend)
  {
    return _database.InsertAsync(friend);
  }

  public Task<int> DeleteFriendAsync(Friend friend)
  {
    return _database.DeleteAsync(friend);
  }

  public Task<int> UpdateFriendAsync(Friend friend)
  {
    return _database.UpdateAsync(friend);
  }

  public Task<int> DeleteAllFriendsAsync() => _database.DeleteAllAsync<Friend>();



  //FS Groups
  public Task<List<FSGroup>> GetFSGroupsAsync()
  {
    return _database.Table<FSGroup>().ToListAsync();
  }

  public Task<int> SaveFSGroupAsync(FSGroup fsgroup)
  {
    return _database.InsertAsync(fsgroup);
  }

  public Task<int> DeleteFSGroupAsync(FSGroup fsgroup)
  {
    return _database.DeleteAsync(fsgroup);
  }

  public Task<int> UpdateGroupAsync(FSGroup fsgroup)
  {
    return _database.UpdateAsync(fsgroup);
  }

  public Task<int> DeleteAllGroupsAsync() => _database.DeleteAllAsync<FSGroup>();

}
```

EDIT: Added the database open method based on @phuzi comments below:
App.xaml.cs

```
namespace Census;

public partial class App : Application
{
  //setup database
  private static Database.Database database;
  private readonly static string filename = "database.db3";
  public static Database.Database Database
  {
    get
    {
      if (database == null)
      {
        database = new Database.Database(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), filename));
      }
      return database;
    }
  }

  public App()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    Application.Current.UserAppTheme = AppTheme.Dark;

    MainPage = new AppShell();
  }
}
```

Not sure where this might be closed?
nuget sqlite-net-pcl
SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic.cdecl (for Android)

End of EDIT

I have no idea how to trace these exceptions. I am sure Visual Studio has a means by which I can figure out where this exception is coming from, but the out of the box vs experience doesn't show me anything except the output message.

Appreciate any insights. It's not an issue, just an annoyance and I know if I don't deal with it, it will cause issues (memory leak) at some point.

Thanks, G

Comment: _"A resource failed to call close"_ sounds like the garbage collector found something implementing `IDisposable` wasn't disposed of properly. probably that instance of `SQLiteAsyncConnection` that sounds like it would implement `IDisposable`

Comment: Taking a look at `SQLiteAsyncConnection` there is a `CloseAsync` method that should probably be called when you're finished with `_database` and/or your instance of `Database`

Comment: Depending upon the size of the application/how often this class is instantiated, this could lead to potentially running out of available connections to your database and being unable to connect.

Comment: @phuzi Thanks for the pointer(!), I'm looking into it now. :)

Comment: Added the database open code to my original question

Comment: Given that you are holding the database in a static, thus holding and reusing that single connection, it doesn't seem to be that. By stepping through code, can you find which line(s) generate those two *"A resource failed to call close."* log lines?

Comment: is this actually causing a problem, or is this just something you came across in the log?

Comment: No problem caused ...yet.

Comment: Normally, it is caused by the streams which are not closed in time after the call. You could manually close the streams after the call.